# Trying to improve the Send / Receive - Data of the Socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm trying to develope a Tool for remote maintenance for a study-project in C# .NET which allows VoIP communication between Server and Client. Additional the **Client** has to send Screenshot Data in raw-Format to the Server and is getting displayed in a PictureBox on the **Server**. (For the beginning I would like to have a data transfer for about 2 Screenshots per second via 1 Gbit LAN - this should be small traffic to handle)

Im pretty new to the Socket developement and created some Code to **Chunk-size** my Data for sending and receiving.

At the Moment, my code works (more or less) well. The Picture is shown in the PictureBox and I get no Error. But I know - this is a really really inefficient way to do this.

My Problem is: The Traffic, and the memory of my Tool is pretty high when I send only 1 Screenshot to the Server (Screenshot has avg. size of ~ 350 kbyte)

My next Problem is: The Server don't know when the Data-transfer is finished. He's always listening for Data but I don't know how to send a command from the Client to stop the Server listening and wait for a new Data-transfer.

**My Questions are:**

1. Could you guys give me a hint how to improve the performance of my Code? Maybe should I do the whole thing **async** ?
2. How to tell the Server when all Chunk_Size Data is received?
3. What is the common way to handle a *Client*-Socket connection? Should I do this like in SQL: Open Connection -> send/receive Data -> Close Connection? 
   Or should I just create one Socket Object and let the connection open?

Please have a look at my Code

**Client:**

```
    //----- Test Send button -------- //
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int CHUNK_SIZE = 8192;
        byte[] dataToSend = ScreenshotToByteArray();
        byte[] buff;

        int loop_length = (dataToSend.Length / CHUNK_SIZE) + 1;
        int modulo = dataToSend.Length % CHUNK_SIZE;
        int offset = 0, i = 0;

        while (i <= loop_length)
        {
            ++i;

            if (i == loop_length) // check for the last piece
            {
                if (modulo != 0)
                {
                    buff = new byte[modulo];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(dataToSend, dataToSend.Length - modulo, buff, 0, modulo);
                    clientSocket.Send(buff, 0, buff.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    break; 
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else // this part is the main chunk piece
            {
                buff = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(dataToSend, offset, buff, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                clientSocket.Send(buff, 0, buff.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                offset += CHUNK_SIZE;
            }
        }
    }


    //------- ScreenImage To Byte Array ------ //
    private static byte[] ScreenshotToByteArray()
    {
        int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Server:**

```
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

    // ---------- Receive Callback --------------//
    private void ReceiveCallback()
    {
        try 
        {
            byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
            int received;
            while((received = ClientSocket.Receive( buff,0, buff.Length, SocketFlags.None )) > 0) 
            {
                mStream.Write( buff, 0, received );
            }
        } 
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            this.ShowErrorDialog( ex.Message );
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            this.ShowErrorDialog( ex.Message );
        } 
    }

    // ------------- Button to show Image ------ //
    private void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if (mStream.Length > 0) 
        {
            this.pictureBox.Image = ConvertByteArrayToImage(mStream.ToArray() );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Anything that can relates to streams or IO is better of doing Async
2. Well you could first send the amount of bytes to receive so the server knows up front when to stop listening
3. Creating connection is a load that should be omitted. A connection pooling mechanism like SQL is preferable.

Maybe a last tip for sending high volume of images;

1. Compress your bitmap to PNG or JPEG
2. Maybe switch from TCP to UDP connection. If the send data is 2 images per second it's best to keep things going and if a message fails.. just get the next one